# Windows Copy/Move freezes when it reaches the SYMBOLIC LINK (Symlink-ed) file/folder

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

Here is a proof-of-concept of the problem I want to describe.

- Create a **`my folder`** and inside it, create a [symlink](https://puvox.software/blog/easiest-method-create-symlink-symbolic/) of ANY other outside file (i.e. `original.txt`)
- Move the `original.txt` to other location, or even just rename. (its symlink still stays in `my folder`)
- Try to copy/move the `my folder`.

Windows copy window will hang forever:

[image]

However, if you delete (or rename) the **symlink** itself, the copy will continue well.

It is very annoying as I have thousands of files (CMS, etc..) symlinked across different projects, and I am searching how to FORCE WINDOWS , NOT TO STUCK on those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot duplicate a hang. In Windows 10 I get instead an error dialog.
You might look for it, as it might have gone below Explorer and is hidden.

[image]

The only solution to avoid such problems is to use another utility that
continues on for such cases.

A batch utility is
[robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).
According to my test it will issue an error, but will copy everything
(including the faulty symlink!).

A GUI utility is [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/en/), which is true to its name.
It will only copy good files, ignoring faulty symlinks.
Setting the option "Nonstop" will not issue any error dialog.

Comment: I think the hang only occurs when the symlink's target is offline/missing/invalid.

Comment: robocopy stops at .symlink files for me. and it tries again after 30 seconds. What i did is i delete the file, it continues then i restore the file.

Comment: I have the same problem. Hang on copy symlink. It's all 1's and 0's you have to wonder what would possibly cause this. All the OS needs to do is look at the 1's and 0's and replicate that, but Windows seems to handle files inefficiently.

Answer (score 0):

As E. van Putten [mentions](https://superuser.com/questions/1488178/windows-copy-move-freezes-when-it-reaches-the-symbolic-link-symlink-ed-file-fo#comment2390617_1488215), Windows Explorer pauzes copying when it encounters a link which cannot be resolved. The good news is that the copy operation will resume automatically as soon as the link can be resolved.

You can do this by finding out the full path of the symbolic link, looking up its target in the file properties and recreating the dir/file.

This is a particularly good solution for when you were in the progress of copying millions of files, and restarting isn't really an option (and the number of invalid links is limited ;)).

*Example for looking up the target of a link:*

*Right-click on the symlink in explorer and click on "properties". You will see the link destination in the "target" field ("doel" in screenshot).*

[image: symbolic link properties]